# Unable to Connect to Internet, make Command Not Found, and cannot install my drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, server, apt, make

**Ubuntu 16.04 xenial - Minimal server - fresh install from USB - Eee PC Asus 1005PEB**

I can't get online.
I think I need drivers because:

1. `ifconfig` shows `inet addr:127.0.0.1`
2. All pings result in: `connect: Network is unreachable`
3. `sudo service network-manager restart` results in: `Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.`

I have an Atheros AR9285 wireless card and found a stable-release package with the assistance of this [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1286503). I copied the driver folder from USB to my ~ directory.
*However,* when I use the `make` command in the package directory, I get this output:

```
The program 'make' can be found in the following packages:
 * make
 * make-guile
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Of course `apt-get` doesn't work because I am offline and while trying to manually install `make`, I found a LOT of dependencies.

How do I get `make` before I expire and get myself online so I can get the packages that I need?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have one, you should be able to use a suitable phone/tablet to connect to the internet using tethering. Connect the device by USB, go to the connections menu on the phone and set up/allow tethering, then your laptop can share the wifi connection of your other device

Comment: This is a good idea.  Sprint doesn't let me tether without paying though.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I'd suggest that you use the following command on the machine without internet:

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install build-essential | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 >downloads.list
```

This will produce an output file in the current directory called downloads.list containing the download URL for all the packages apt needs to install the build-essential package.

Then you can copy this file to your USB drive for your internet connected machine to download them, if your internet connected machine is running linux you could easily download all the dependencies in one go with the following command:

```
wget -i downloads.list
```

Which will read the downloads.list file and download each URL listed in it, if not then you would need to go to each listed URL and download the file yourself.

You could then just take the USB drive to your other machine and simply run the following command from the directory containing the downloaded .deb files:

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Note I have suggested using the build-essential package as this package includes the other packages that you will need for compiling a piece of software such as the compiler itself (gcc) which will save you some time or you would end up needing to repeat this process over and over to get everything you will need.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the response:  E: Unable to locate package build-essential.

Comment: Ah, seems this will be because your system has never been online it doesn't know of the full list of packages available in the repository so I looked up the dependencies for build-essential then it's dependencies and so on then got the URL's for them which gives this list https://www.dropbox.com/s/fus0vtf6vm5thod/download.list?dl=0 some of these packages are probably already installed but if you fetch all of them least you wont be missing any, hope that helps.